# Trying to figure out how to make a next and previous button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Hey guys so I'm trying to program a next and previous button for a menu on my game. I've made a script that I've attached to a sprite that has a Collider. When this collider is clicked it will load the next image. How would I go about creating a previous and next button, would I just make another gameobject and assign this scripts to them?

Here is the script.

```
public class InfoButtonLoad : GameButton
{
    public static InfoButtonLoad the;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] infoSelect;
    public int infoSwitch;

    void Start()
    {
        the = this;
    }

    public override void PressAction()
    {
        infoSwitch++;
        InfoButtonCase();
    }

    public void InfoButtonCase()
    {
        switch (infoSwitch)
        {
            case 1:
                infoSelect[0].SetActive(true);
                infoSelect[1].SetActive(false);
                break;
            case 2:
                infoSelect[0].SetActive(false);
                infoSelect[1].SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 3:
                infoSelect[1].SetActive(false);
                infoSelect[2].SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 4:
                infoSelect[2].SetActive(false);
                infoSelect[3].SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 5:
                infoSelect[3].SetActive(false);
                infoSelect[4].SetActive(true);
                infoSwitch = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    void HideInfo()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < infoSelect.Length; i++)
            infoSelect[i].SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would be to use the same script but add a variable to tell if its a Next or previous Button like this:

```
public class InfoButtonLoad : GameButton
{
    public static InfoButtonLoad the;
    public bool isNext;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] infoSelect;
    public int infoSwitch;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    public override void PressAction()
    {
        if(isNext){
            infoSwitch++;
            if(infoSwitch == 5){
                infoSwitch = 0;
            }
        }else{
            infoSwitch--;
            if(infoSwitch == 0){
                infoSwitch = 4;
            }
        }
        InfoButtonCase();
    }

    public void InfoButtonCase()
    {
        foreach(GameObject info in infoSelect)
        {
            info.SetActive(false);
        }
        infoSelect[infoSwitch].SetActive(true);

    }
    void HideInfo()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < infoSelect.Length; i++)
            infoSelect[i].SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

I also removed your switch as it could have been replaced by fewer lines. All you have to do is set the script in both your buttons and make check isNext in the Next button in the Inspector.

Comment: OP can't use the same script though since he uses a singleton pattern `the = this;` ;) But this doesn't invalidate the answer of course

Comment: And the `foreach` is probably fine but slightly more efficient would be to only disable the current object, then update the index, then enable the new object but thats just details ;)

Comment: Thank you very much @derHugo , I fixed the code but left the foreach loop as a more general answer but you are definitely right ! Thanks.